# What effects do choices in Wings of Liberty have in Heart of the Swarm?

Tags: starcraft-2

As per [my other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108375/what-is-the-canonical-option-for-the-wings-of-liberty-split-missions), I know that choices made in Wings of Liberty affect (at minimum) dialog in Heart of the Swarm.

What other effects do these past choices have on the campaign, if any? Are there any other choices that get carried through?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read it there, Some dialogs are different based on your previous choices but no major changes.[link](http://www.gamefront.com/sc2-parts-of-heart-of-the-swarm-will-differ-based-on-your-choices-in-wings/) to an official interview concerning this

Their are no change reported so far

A full interview :
[link](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/8226551)

Comment: While this is helpful, I'm personally looking for specifically what the difference is between the things that change. I want to know what it is on the other side if I do things differently.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the dialogs in HOTS are an aftermath of some of the choices you made in WOL. I am not 100% sure, though, since I'm only about to finish my first playthrough.

> Note the dialog with Nova mid game; for example, the dialog with Izsha about the Terran having an airs uperiority on Char. Based on my WOL, it matches the choices I made in my last playthrough of WOL: nova missions / Tosch mission and No Nydus / No air

Comment: Hello, Atlas, and welcome to Arqade! Do you have any other details you can add? Right now, you're not providing anything I haven't mentioned in the question body (about the dialog changing).

Comment: Hi, and thanks. I found a source stating that your choices in WOL do not affect how HOTS turns out. (sorry for the missing source)

Answer (score 0):

some choices in WOL does have effect in HOTS like when i helped Nova in WOL she said in the end of the second mission of HOTS ''well well Jim Raynor you helped me with my Tosh problem and i appreciate that but a girls gotta do what a girls gotta do'' while when i helped Tosh she said ''well well jim raynor if you helped me with my Tosh problem i might have looked away but you chose poorly'' and Zagara on char (cant remeber dialogue) if you flood the tunnels with lava she says one thing while if you destroy the platform she says another thing