# HoTS 2nd mission, how to stop Nova?

Tags: starcraft-2

> In the second mission, Nova finds Raynor and says that if he had chosen to help her, she might be a little bit less cruel. I chose to help Nova over Tosh in all my playthroughs of the Wings of Liberty campaign.

Is there a way to link the HotS campaign to a WoL save file so that she knows I chose her over Tosh?

Comment: Wow! I'm pretty suprised that game remember and use past quests to make better storyline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have an actual save game from your campaign where you chose Nova over Tosh the game should automatically pick that up.  If you don't have a save game you get the [canonical options](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/108375/20818).

This doesn't change her actions though, only her dialog.

Comment: ok, probably a bug then... (I saw a lot of sound bugs when I lost a mission and restarted from a checkpoint).

Her second dialog might've made me rage less on that part of the mission though.

Comment: Probably, I had lots of issues with Battle.net yesterday.  Including losing my entire campaign progress on WoL for most of the day.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  I chose Nova over Tosh in WoL, I have the saved game, and I got the [incorrect] canonical dialogue. Is there another version of the dialogue?

Comment: Yes, she says something to the effect of, "Even though you helped me out with my Tosh problem, I've still got a job to do".  Then proceeds with the rest of the event.

Comment: that would piss me off, but not make me rage...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do, either way the action is still the same.

I was curious of that myself and I ran through all the missions on easy on WoL and she said "Although you helped me with my Tosh problem..."